# laravel 5.2 redirect after registration by id

Tags: redirect, laravel-5

I've found here some examples, but they are not answering how to **redirect registered user to his own profile by id**.

`protected $redirectPath = '/profile/view/'.$user->id;` Did not help.
I have a project where users are being authorized without email confirmation and they are sent to `/home` after registration.

Route to user profile is: `/profile/view/id` (id is unique of course).
I managed to send them there after login (in AuthController :

```
public function authenticated($request,$user)
{ 
    return  redirect('/profile/view/'.$user->id);
}
```

but redirect to profile after registration I can't handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach 1.

Let users view their own profile without ID.

**route** (make ID optional):

```
Route::get('profile/view/{id?}', ...);
```

**controller**:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (is_null($id) { //set id of currently signed in user if id == null
        $id = Auth::user()->id; 
    }

    //continue as before

}
```

---

#### Approach 2.

Modify routes so redirect happens to correct url.

> **Note**: order of routes is important

```
Route::get('profile/view', function() {
    return redirect()->route('profile.view', ['id' => Auth::user()->id]);
});

Route::get('profile/view/{id}', ...)->name('profile.view');
```

> **Note**: in both approaches `auth` middleware is a must, else you going to get error if user is not logged in (`PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line X`)

With both approaches you just redirect user to `profile/view`:

1. is shown profile (without ID in URL)
2. is redirected to proper url `profile/view/ID`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! First variant is ok.. I just added  }elseif(isset($id)){ //continue as before